# How to pass data on click to modal's backdrop to receive in onDidDismiss callback function? Ionic 3 Angular 6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular6

How do I can pass data to modal's onDidDismiss by clicking on modal's backdrop?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I cannot found the answer for title's question. So I will post here how I did resolve this problem and received modal's data on onDidDismiss function on modal's invoker page:

On the caller page:

```js
@IonicPage()
@Component({...})
export class ExamplePage {

  constructor(...){...}

  private _showModal() {

    let modal = this._modalCtrl.create(
      'ModalPage',
      {...},
      {
        showBackdrop: true,
        enableBackdropDismiss: false,
      });
    modal.present();

    modal.onDidDismiss((res)=>{
      console.log("_showModal.modal.onDidDismiss: ", res);
    });

  }

}
```

And on modal's page:

```js
@IonicPage()
@Component({...})
export class ModalPage{

  constructor(...){...}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    let _modal = this._elRef.nativeElement;

    while (_modal.tagName != "ION-MODAL") {
      _modal = _modal.parentNode;
    }

    let _unlistenBackdrop = this._renderer.listen(_modal.querySelector('ion-backdrop'), "click", e=>{
      this._dismiss();
    });

  }

  private _dismiss(){
    let obj = {};

    // ... feed the object with whatever you need;

    obj = {test: true};

    this._viewCtrl.dismiss(obj);
  }

}
```

Hope to help some coder who came here with the same doubt. :)

If someone knows a better way to reach the same result, please, post it in an answer below. ;D

Thanks!